# Web socket, stateful sessions, multiple clients accessing the same session, and AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We have web sockets + rest, stateful socket sessions, multiple clients accessing the same stateful session, and AWS ELB.

What is the best way to allow multiple clients to access the same session(s) through AWS ELB while also being able to horizontally scale our servers.

It would be great if we could do a custom "User ID" rather than a cookie or via IP, through the ELB, but afaik that isn't possible.

I realize this is horribly open ended but I'm not sure yet how to be more specific.

Comment: ELBs have "sticky sessions" as an option, which will keep a particular user (using a cookie) on a particular backend instance for the duration of their session. You can let them assign servers, or you can use [application-controlled sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application) for more control. Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the link and the response! 
Sorry maybe I'm missing something obvious in there - but how does this take care of multiple clients accessing the same session? Wouldn't a new login (if on the same account, but a different computer) get a new cookie and therefore have a new session? Is there a way to say "hey server, if this user logs in on another machine, make sure to route them to the right server and hand them the right cookie?